# React Component member resets to undefined after rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component which makes HTTP requests using a separate client. When attempting the use the client while handling a click event, the call to `this.client.getChannel()` fails because `this.client` is now undefined.

[image]

```
import * as React from 'react';

import Client, { Channel } from '../modules/Client';
import { Container, Grid, GridItem, Placeholder } from '../modules/UI';
import ChannelsList from '../components/ChannelsList';
import Loading from '../components/Loading';


interface Props {}

interface State {
  channel?: Channel,
  channels: Channel[],
  loading: boolean
}


export default class ChannelsPage extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  public client: Client = new Client();


  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      channels: [],
      loading: true
    }

    this.onChannelSelected.bind(this);
  }


  public componentDidMount() {
     this.client.getChannels() // THIS WORKS :)
       .then((objects: Channel[]) => {
         this.setState({
           channels: objects,
           loading: false
         });
       });
  }


  public onChannelSelected(event: any, channel: Channel) {
    this.client.getChannel(channel) // THIS DOES NOT WORK, this.client is undefined
      .then((object: Channel) => {
        this.setState({ channel: object });
      });
  }


  public render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <h1>Channels</h1>
        <Grid>
          <GridItem width={'1/3'}>
            { this.state.loading ? <Loading /> : <ChannelsList channels={ this.state.channels } onChannelSelected={ this.onChannelSelected } /> }
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem width={'2/3'}>
            { this.state.channel ? <p>{ this.state.channel.uid }</p> : <Placeholder>Select a channel to view details</Placeholder> }
          </GridItem>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm confused as to why `this.client` is being set to `undefined` after rendering. I would like to preserve `this.client` as long as the component is alive to make any HTTP requests, especially since the client handles caching responses for me.

Why is is `this.client` being set to undefined before being called in `onChannelSelected` and is there a way to preserve it?

Comment: `this.onChannelSelected.bind(this);` should be `this.onChannelSelected = this.onChannelSelected.bind(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change onChannel Selected function like this

```
public onChannelSelected = (event: any, channel: Channel) => {
    this.client.getChannel(channel) // THIS DOES NOT WORK, this.client is undefined
      .then((object: Channel) => {
        this.setState({ channel: object });
      });
  }
```

Or change the declaration in constructor

```
this.onChannelSelected = this.onChannelSelected.bind(this);
```